# 'suggest' mapping for ElasticSearch index doesn't return results

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an index that looks like the following

```
[question_index] => Array
        (
            [mappings] => Array
                (
                    [QUESTION] => Array
                        (
                            [properties] => Array
                                (
                                    [body] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => string
                                        )

                                    [general_suggest] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => completion
                                            [analyzer] => simple
                                            [payloads] => 1
                                            [preserve_separators] => 1
                                            [preserve_position_increments] => 1
                                            [max_input_length] => 50
                                        )
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

I added the suggest mapping with the following PHP code.

```
$param['index']    = 'question_index';
$param['type']      = 'QUESTION';
$param['body']      = array(
    '_source'       => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties'    => array(
        'body'      => array('type' => 'string'),
        'general_suggest'   => array(
            'type'              => 'completion',
            'index_analyzer'    => 'simple',
            'search_analyzer'   => 'simple',
            'payloads'          => true
        )
    )
);
$result     = $client->indices()->putMapping($param);
```

I tried to get suggested results with the following PHP code

```
    $param                                  = array();
    $param['index']                     = 'question_index';
    $param['body']['text']                  = 'someth';//should return 'something' as a suggest
    $param['body']['completion']['field']   = 'general_suggest';
    $result     = $client->suggest($param);
```

Whenever I run the above code I get the following errors.

```
Array
(
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 5
            [successful] => 0
            [failed] => 5
            [failures] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [index] => question_index
                            [shard] => 0
                            [reason] => BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[question_index][0] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to execute suggest]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[[suggest] does not support [field]]; 
                        )
```

Anyone know what could be the problem here? Are my indexes or the parameters I'm using setup incorrectly?

Please note that I'm using the PHP client library and not accessing the API directly via HTTP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work with the following setup.

### 1. Setup the index first

```
$client      = new Elasticsearch\Client();
$param           = array();
$param['index'] = 'user_index';
$param['type']  = 'user';
$param['body']  = new stdClass();               
$client->create($param);
```

### 2. Setup the mapping for suggestions

```
$param  = array();
$param['index']                 = 'user_index';
$param['type']                  = 'user';
$param['body']                  = array(
    'properties'    => array(
        'body'          => array(
            'type'  => 'string'
        ),
        'autosuggest'   => array(
            'type'              => 'completion',
            'index_analyzer'    => 'simple',
            'search_analyzer'   => 'simple',
            'payloads'          => true
        )
    )
);
$client->indices()->putMapping($param);
```

### 3. Add documents to the index

```
//assume $user is an object available to you
$params = array();
$params['body']  = array(
    'autosuggest'   => array(
        'input'     => [$user->full_name, $user->username],
        'output'    => $user->full_name,
        'payload'   => array(
            'id'        => $user->id,
            'full_name' => $user->full_name,
            'username'  => $user->username,
            'type'      => 'user'
        )
    ),
    'body'          => $user->full_name . "(@{$user->username})",
);
$params['index'] = 'user_index';
$params['type']  = 'user';
$params['id']    = $user->id;
$client->index($params);
```

### 4. Finally, the way to get suggestions

```
$client             = new Elasticsearch\Client();
$param              = array();
$param['index']     = 'user_index';
$param['body']['search_suggest']['text']                    = 'search_query_here';
$param['body']['search_suggest']['completion']['field']    = 'autosuggest';
$results        = $client->suggest($param);
```

Comment: how would you work with multilingual fields? lets say we want to get suggestions on a products title, which we store in 3 languages. something like `'input.en'     => $product->name['en'],  'input.de'     => $product->name['de'], ...`

Comment: Depends on how you have the data. You could create different indexes depending on the language and switch out the correct index when the user searches for it. Otherwise you'd have to have one index and keep a column for each language. Personally I prefer the first method.

Comment: i finished with having multiple suggestions per language, in this case it would look like: `$param['body']['search_suggest-en']['text']` vs `$param['body']['search_suggest-de']['text']` but its a bit duplicite, since they all store the same set of data in the `payload` fields set

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap your query in another array like so:

```
$param                              = array();
$param['index']                     = 'question_index';
$param['body']['suggestions']['text']                  = 'someth';//should return 'something' as a suggest
$param['body']['suggestions']['completion']['field']   = 'general_suggest';
$result     = $client->suggest($param);
```

The $param variable would then look like:

```
$param = array(
    'index' => 'question_index',
    'body'  => array(
        'suggestions' => array(
            'text' => 'someth',
            'completion' => array(
                'field' => 'general_suggest'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Note that "suggestions" has been added ; you can replace it by whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, this was the conclusion I came to as well. I also needed to add  the index and the mapping properly.